# What is the lifespan of files saved to CFFileServlet with Coldfusion

Tags: file, coldfusion, temp, ttl

I have to serve captcha image (in Coldfusion) without saving permanent files per request, so I am using cfimage without a source destination and the action set to captcha.

This returns a file like this:
[image]

From what I've tested, these files are seem to be temporary they become unavailable after around 5min. This fits my need, but I've been trying to find documentation regarding CFFileServlet, how it works, etc... with no luck...

Any thoughts?

Thanks, Phill

Comment: I have never had to use cffileservlet before, but I have created files in the tmp directory of CF, and the one thing I know is that CF doesn't automatically delete them, you have to have your code do that for you.  Are you sure your code isn't overwriting your captcha?

Comment: I'll check on that, it is possible that's its just overwriting files as the function gets called again

Answer (score 1):

Not documented AFAIK, and yes they get deleted around 5 minutes after created.